# Failed to obtain Jenkins slave

Tags: windows, jenkins, slave

In my scenario Jenkins master is available in Linux machine and i can access this in my Local windows machine also.
I created one windows slave using launch method as "Launch agent by connecting to the master".As per guidelines , i created one folder in my windows and i pasted that slave and agent jars in that folder.

While I am trying to run the slave-agent i am getting error like below. (Screenshot attached)
I tried with 2nd option as well i.e i took the provided command in Jenkins slave and i pasted that into command. again it is giving failed to connect error message. Please find below error message.

I am new to this configuration.
Do i need provide my slave machine ip into the master machine or do i need to install any other things related to this. can someone please help me out.

```
Failed to obtain http://ip:7394839:computer/winslave1/slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown....etc
```

[Slave-agent error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvkxS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. In my case whenever we are creating new slave it is generating new IP which is not having server. Here just we are creating another node for the existing server.

Whenever we are launching the slave using agent.jar with the slave IP we are getting timed out error. Instead of going with slave IP if we go with master IP , agent is launching successfully.

Please find below example.

If i try with slave IP(Below IP)
java -jar D:\Jenkins\agent.jar -jnlpUrl we are getting error
http://120.231.140:8080/computer/My_slave_node_name_Windows10/slave-agent.jnlp -secret anHexadecimal_Long_Number5d094b1f577bc772b65b7277ac57 -workDir "D:\Jenkins"

Below IP is master IP. Agent launched successfully.

java -jar D:\Jenkins\agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://120.241.141:8080/computer/My_slave_node_name_Windows10/slave-agent.jnlp -secret anHexadecimal_Long_Number5d094b1f577bc772b65b7277ac57 -workDir "D:\Jenkins"

There is change in IP for slave and master. If i launch the slave ip from the cmd we are getting a timed out error.

Answer (score 0):

The other three possibilities are

1. Whitelist slave IP in master Instance security groups level(all traffic or required ports).
2. By default windows server will block with IE security settings so diable by following below.
   "Enter Server Manager in Windows search to start Server manager application. Select Local Server. Navigate to the IE Enhanced Security Configuration property, select the current setting to open the property page, select the Off option button for the desired users, and then select OK"
3. Configure a port number for TCP JNLP connection and whitelist it on instance security groups.
   Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Enable security > TCP port for JNLP agents: Fixed.